# Python sort list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
AccountValues = [
{'portfolio_ref': 1, 'tag': 'FullInit', 'value': '20642.95', 'currency': 'USD', 'percent': 0.0}, 
{'portfolio_ref': 1, 'tag': 'FullMaint', 'value': '21350.54', 'currency': 'USD', 'percent': 0.0}, 
{'portfolio_ref': 1, 'tag': 'NetLiq', 'value': '70976.05', 'currency': 'USD', 'percent': 100.0} ]
```

Simple mission per SQL description: Order by portfolio_ref ASC, percent DESC

What I tried unsuccessfully:

```
sorted(AccountsValues, key=lambda x: (x[1],-x[4]))
```

which gives me

```
KeyError: 1
```

Second attempt:

```
import operator
result = sorted(myAccountsValues, key=itemgetter('percent'))
```

which fails to sort on percentage.

Comment: What about what you tried didn't work? It's always helpful to be clear about what you tried, what you expected, and what you got instead. For instance did you get an error message? Or just the wrong result? Did you make any attempts at debugging?

Comment: The reason your second attempt didn't seem to work is that your data is *already* sorted on percentage...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict.__getitem__` or its syntactic sugar `[]`:

```
res = sorted(AccountValues, key=lambda x: (x['portfolio_ref'], -x['percent']))
```

Remember that dictionaries are not indexable by integers. Historically (pre-3.6), they are not even ordered. Even in Python 3.7, you cannot directly extract the *n*th key or value.

Result:

```
print(res)

[{'portfolio_ref': 1, 'tag': 'NetLiq', 'value': '70976.05', 'currency': 'USD', 'percent': 100.0},
 {'portfolio_ref': 1, 'tag': 'FullInit', 'value': '20642.95', 'currency': 'USD', 'percent': 0.0},
 {'portfolio_ref': 1, 'tag': 'FullMaint', 'value': '21350.54', 'currency': 'USD', 'percent': 0.0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to combine all the things you did correctly: sort keys as a tuple *and* the proper way of referencing a `dict` entry:

```
>>> sorted(AccountValues, key=lambda x: (x["portfolio_ref"], -x["percent"]))
[{'tag': 'NetLiq', 'portfolio_ref': 1, 'value': '70976.05', 'percent': 100.0, 'currency': 'USD'},
 {'tag': 'FullInit', 'portfolio_ref': 1, 'value': '20642.95', 'percent': 0.0, 'currency': 'USD'},
 {'tag': 'FullMaint', 'portfolio_ref': 1, 'value': '21350.54', 'percent': 0.0, 'currency': 'USD'}]
```

Better yet, use

```
sorted(AccountValues, key=itemgetter("portfolio_ref", "percent"))
```

Your first attempt failed because `x[1]` and `x[4]` are not valid references into the dictionaries: you have to use the labels you originally gave, not relative positions.

Your second attempt is deficient only because you don't have the secondary sort key.

Comment: As I was pasting, also note @jpp posted same response, gj to both